# MongoDB remove 3rd level embedded document

Tags: java, python, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have a Document, I want to use $pull or other good way to remove only device where
"mobile_id": "opr_134" from devices list of address.

```
{
    "user_id": "eamn",
    "address": [{
        "address_id": 32,
        "city_name": "DP 1000"
        "devices": [{
            "mobile_id": "opr_123",
            "created_at": 2132,
            "device": "company"
        },{
            "mobile_id": "opr_134",
            "created_at": 2134,
            "device": "company2"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Please suggest an atomic way to remove this device.

Comment: I would do it in the application side. I would get the object, replace the array in your api and then I would run .findOneAndReplace. Despite of the fact if you can do it with the mongo cli, I think is better to do it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do the job:

```
 db.triLevel.update({},{$pull:{"address.$[].devices":{"mobile_id":"opr_134"}}})
```

Comment: Your answer is working correct, but I would love to know why it is working but not when done like:
`db.triLevel.update({},{$pull:{"address.$[].devices.$.mobile_id":"opr_134"}})`

or

`db.triLevel.update({},{$pull:{"address.$[].devices.$[].mobile_id":"opr_134"}})`

    I think might be we have to tell in first part go up to this level `"address.$[].devices"` and in second part find this match `"mobile_id":"opr_134"` and pull this part of first part's array

Comment: The last array is "devices" , you dont have more nested array levels after devices ...